# Stripe Connect: Can Connected accounts become Customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm considering adopting Stripe connect.
What I want to do is One user will be able to both that receive and pay.

What I now understand is to create a custom account user and create a payment from the platform to the custom account with Destination charge.

Can a Custom account user pay the platform as a consumer?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of potential ways to make this work, but I'd recommend you reach out to Support and tell them about your usecase and make sure it's something that Stripe can support first - and also ask them this there: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: @floatingLomas Tanks! I'll try to contact to a support.

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario you can make a stripe Customer and his Connect account both having same bank account linked. So when you initialise to pay the platform it will be charged from same bank account as well as when receiving payout the same bank account will be credited.